# Kendo UI Chart ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo

JSON возвращает date в формате "date" : "20150410",полученный JSON ответ я напрямую передаю field в kendo chart

```
  categoryAxis: {

                field: "date",
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                }
            }
```

Мне нужен дата в формате 10.04.2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал конкатенацию:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            var d = data.data[i].date;
            data.data[i].date = d.substring(6, 8) + '.' + d.substring(4, 6) + '.' + d.substring(0, 4);
        }//10.04.2015
```